# MongoDB Insert Issue

Tags: mongodb

This is from MongoDB.

I am following [this tutorial](http://tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_insert_document.htm).

I have the collection as shown below:

```
$ show collections
mycol
mycollection
system.indexes
test
tutorialspoint
```

Then when I attempt to insert a record in to the collection, using the syntax below, I get the error:

```
2014-04-18T08:03:55.168-0400 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

db.mycol.insert({
   _id: ObjectId(7df78ad8902c),
   title: 'MongoDB Overview', 
   description: 'MongoDB is no sql database',
   by: 'tutorials point',
   url: 'http://www.tutorialspoint.com',
   tags: ['mongodb', 'database', 'NoSQL'],
   likes: 100
})
```

Below is the copy/paste from mongodb

```
 db.mycol.insert({
...    _id: ObjectId(7df78ad8902c),
...    title: 'MongoDB Overview',
...    description: 'MongoDB is no sql database',
...    by: 'tutorials point',
...    url: 'http://www.tutorialspoint.com',
...    tags: ['mongodb', 'database', 'NoSQL'],
...    likes: 100
... })
2014-04-18T08:03:55.168-0400 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Comment: The example is flawed as `ObjectId(7df78ad8902c)` isn't valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Try the insert without the _id field. This is automatically generated by Mongodb.

Like this:

```
   db.mycol.insert({
        title: 'MongoDBOverview',
        description: 'MongoDBisnosqldatabase',
        by: 'tutorialspoint',
        url: 'http: //www.tutorialspoint.com',
        tags: [
            'mongodb',
            'database',
            'NoSQL'
        ],
        likes: 100
    });
```

If you want to use the `_id` field:
Mongodb docs: [Insert a document using the _id field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#insert-a-document-without-specifying-an-id-field)

Ex: `_id: 10`

> The value of _id must be unique within the collection to avoid
>   duplicate key error.

Comment: without using __id field Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The value needs to be in quotes. Also, the string in the example is the wrong length. Insert something without specifying the _id field, then do a db.mycol.find() to see the correct format. The field is 12 bytes according to the documentation. The 24-character string is using 2 hex characters per byte. (NOTE: I am also a mongoDB noob, so I am sure there may be flaws with this answer.)